# Converting XML element names to camelCase format using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, wso2, xslt-1.0

I need to transform all element names in a XML to camelCase naming strategy with XSLT.

Here is a response from coming server:

```
<ROOT_ELEMENT>
        <ELEMENT_1>2595959584</ELEMENT_1>
        <Element_Two>Lorem</Element_Two>
        <eLement_Three>Ipsum</eLement_Three>

        <BIRTH_date>
           <Day>21</Day>
           <Month>09</Month>
           <Year>1955</Year>
        </BIRTH_date>
 </ROOT_ELEMENT>
```

Here is what I want to transform:

```
<rootElement>
        <element1>2595959584</element1>
        <elementTwo>Lorem</elementTwo>
        <elementThree>Ipsum</elementThree>      
        <birthDate>
           <day>21</day>
           <month>09</month>
           <year>1955</year>
        </birthDate>
</rootElement>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there will be at most one `_` separator in the element name, and assuming that the names contain no non-ASCII characters, you can use:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:param name="upper-case" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'"/>
    <xsl:param name="lower-case" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="name" select="name()" />
    <xsl:variable name="word2" select="substring-after($name, '_')" />
    <xsl:variable name="new-name">
        <xsl:value-of select="translate(substring-before(concat($name, '_'), '_'), $upper-case, $lower-case)"/> 
        <xsl:value-of select="translate(substring($word2, 1, 1), $lower-case, $upper-case)"/>   
        <xsl:value-of select="translate(substring($word2, 2), $upper-case, $lower-case)"/>  
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:element name="{$new-name}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

### Added:

If (as it seems) you're using a processor that supports the XSLT `str:tokenize()` extension function, you could do:

**XSLT 1.0 + EXSLT**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:str="http://exslt.org/strings"
extension-element-prefixes="str">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:param name="upper-case" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'"/>
    <xsl:param name="lower-case" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="new-name">
        <xsl:for-each select="str:tokenize(name(), '_')">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="position() = 1">
                    <xsl:value-of select="translate(., $upper-case, $lower-case)"/>   
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise>
                    <xsl:value-of select="translate(substring(., 1, 1), $lower-case, $upper-case)"/>   
                    <xsl:value-of select="translate(substring(., 2), $upper-case, $lower-case)"/>
                </xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:for-each> 
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:element name="{$new-name}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This removes the limit on the number of `_` separators an element name can have. The other restriction remains: every possible character that can appear in an element name and has upper-case and lower-case variants must be listed in the `$upper-case` and `$lower-case` parameters.

Answer (score 0):

In XSLT 3.0 it's

```
string-join(tokenize(name(), '_') ! 
  (upper-case(substring(., 1, 1)) || lower-case(substring(., 2))))
```

In 1.0 it's much more difficult, but still possible (at least, if your element names only use ASCII letters). You'll need a recursive named template to do the tokenizing (you can find one at http://www.exslt.org, look for `str:tokenize` in the strings module), and within the named template where you are processing one token, you'll need to use `translate($x, 'abc...z', 'ABC...Z')` to do the case conversion.

You can avoid the recursion and simplify the logic if you know there will only be one underscore in the name; in that case you can use `substring-before()` and `substring-after()` to get the two parts of the name.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But i just have met with XSLT today. I haven't known anything about XSLT yet. Is there any complete solution for this problem.

Comment: I'm not prepared to write XSLT 1.0 code for a problem like this, it's absolutely no fun at all. Move forward to a later version, and people like me are more likely to offer help.

Comment: Actually, it's more difficult in XSLT 3.0 too: the above will return PascalCase, while the requirement is for camelCase (first character is in lowercase).

Answer (score 0):

One more way to capitalize first letter in **XSLT 1.0** is as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

<xsl:variable name="smallcase" select="'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'" />
<xsl:variable name="uppercase" select="'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'" />

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:variable name="convertElementName">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains(local-name(.),'_')">
                <xsl:value-of
                    select="concat(translate(substring-before(local-name(.),'_'), $uppercase, $smallcase),
                            translate(substring(substring-after(local-name(.),'_'),1,1), $smallcase, $uppercase),
                            translate(substring(substring-after(local-name(.),'_'),2,string-length(local-name(.))-1), $uppercase, $smallcase))" />
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="translate(local-name(.), $uppercase, $smallcase)" />
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:variable>

    <xsl:element name="{$convertElementName}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:attribute name="{local-name(.)}">
        <xsl:value-of select="." />
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains(name(), '_')">
            <xsl:element name="{concat(substring-before(lower-case(name()), '_'), substring(substring-after(upper-case(name()), '_'), 1,1), substring(substring-after(lower-case(name()), '_'), 2))}">
                <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:element name="{lower-case(name())}">
                    <xsl:apply-templates/>
                </xsl:element>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

One more Answer if it is possible use this code.

Comment: This question is tagged XSLT 1.0. Your answer requires XSLT 2.0.

Comment: Where does lower-case function come from? I got this error.

javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: Could not find function: lower-case

Comment: This answer was XSLT 2.0